# Как cделать так чтобы auto_increment id пользователя в таблице users начинались с 10000 при добавлении,если уже есть пользователи с id 1,2,3,..?

Tags: postgresql

Как cделать так чтобы auto_increment id пользователя в таблице users начинались с 10000 при добавлении

Comment: Сделать так можно (с костылями), но нужно ли? Возможно, если вы опишите какую имеено задачу вы хотите решить таким способом, то вам предложат другое решение. Если надо вот прямо как описано - то, наверное, лучше всего будет завести отдельную колонку для этих значений, а сам ID не трогать. Для колонки можно отдельный sequence завести, наверное, с минимумом в 10000

Comment: Делаете ALTER SEQUENCE соответствующего генератора - и всё.

Comment: @Akina а это не перезапишет уже имеющиеся ID?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб С какого перепугу-то? как генератор связан с уже имеющимися данными?

Comment: @Akina, я не знаю) Мне просто показалось, что это может так работать, вот и уточняю. Коли не меняет - тогда да, вы правильно сказали - изменить генератор и всё)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно выполнить такой запрос

`mysql`

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

`postgresql`

```
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 10000;
```